# Directory/File based logging selektor

Tags: node.js, logging, log4j

I am looking for a logging solution for my node.js app that would allow me to set the logging level via file/folder selectors.

For example I would like to be able to set the logging for all files in /app/schema to 'info'. And all the rest to 'error'.

Exemplary configuration:

```
{
  "*":"error",
  "/app/schema":"info" //<--Regex expression would be great too.
}
```

I constantly comment/uncomment/remove logging statements when I need to examine something. I would rather do that via a configuration change and leave the logging files intact. A global debugging level just creates too way to much noise and volume (which matters when storing logs).

Is there something like this? [Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) is similar, you can set logging  level on package level.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, I'd suggest Bunyan, it lets you configure as many log streams and log levels as you like, i.e. from the [docs](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#streams-introduction):

```
var log = bunyan.createLogger({
  name: 'myapp',
  streams: [
    {
      level: 'info',
      stream: process.stdout            // log INFO and above to stdout
    },
    {
      level: 'error',
      path: '/var/tmp/myapp-error.log'  // log ERROR and above to a file
    }
  ]
});
```

You'll have to set up the logic for each path with each log-level.

Comment: Bunyan is great. I refined the question a bit. I like to be able to specify a fine grained logging level configuration on a file level.

Comment: I believe you could just push all logs on the same level and then filter using the `bunyan cli` app, i.e.: `tail -f /logs/prod.log | bunyan -l INFO` that way you filter only INFO upwards, more over if you wrap some functionality onto your logs you'll be able to ad a custom "filter", i.e.: `log.info("identificator",actualLog);`. The rest is up to how you'll code your app.

Comment: good idea. my concern would be the volume it generates and the associated costs. its always good to have everything, maybe its the way to do it.

Comment: I usually set up the log level based on the environment, then each time the script runs, it'll check the date and create the log file with a basic YYYYMMDD timestamp, if you need it, zipping old files should not be that complicated ;)